# Given a data ingestion platform with various use cases, what would a good data store be for user configuration data?

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, apache-kafka

The initial use case for our multi-tenant data ingestion platform was to pull in RSS data, file meta data and SQL query results.  For this, ElasticSearch was chosen as the data store and Kafka as the microservices message broker.

New streaming, low-latency and time-series data are another requirement.  Thus, ElasticSearch is not a contender for this in favor of Aerospike or InfluxDB.

The initial plan was to put user account and configuration data into an ElasticSearch index/topic, as I wanted to have everything in ES.

Based on our growing requirements I can see we may have a variety of different database types depending on the use case.  Would continuing to store this information in ES still be a good idea?

Using Kafka as the micro-services bus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking in a Kafka tag, I'm assuming that no matter the use-case and its data store, Kafka will definitely be used.

So why not store user configuration in Kafka?

It sounds like a fairly small topic, so you can set the retention to 100 years or something similar. If you expect user configuration to change often, you can make it a compacted topic. Now when you microservices start, they just need to read this topic and store the configuration in their memory. This will give you the flexibility to choose the right data store for your application data without worrying too much about the configuration.

Comment: I had not considered that.  However things like user account details, email address, passwords, roles, user projects, etc. - I would want to store those in a regular database, then populate the logged in user's object with those details.

Comment: Regular database means MySQL to me :)